# Receving 403 forbidden from Custom Domain in AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm trying to build a serverless app with AWS. My API is working fine, but my custom domain is not. I'm receiving a 403 forbidden answer. This is how it's configured my custom domain:

[image]

And then I'm using the Target URL provided by this Custom Domain in Route 53 as CNAME. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you use the API Gateway endpoint directly (i.e. bypassing the custom domain)? If not, it could be an issue with the API Gateway -> Lambda permissions.

Comment: The API gateway endpoint works, what doesn't work is the target domain offered by custom domain, neither the domain used in Route 53 with CNAME

Comment: And your CNAME is pointing to the `*.cloudfront.net` domain, not the `*.execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com` one?

Comment: The CNAME is pointing to *.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com which is the one that custom domain gaves me. How can I get the cloudfront domain?

Comment: If you go to API Gateway -> Custom Domain Names, there should be a CloudFront domain listed under "Target Domain Name".

Comment: I updated to clodfront url, let's wait for some time to check it works

Comment: It's working now. @Tom can you submit an answer so I accept it?

Comment: Done! Glad it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CNAME should point to the CloudFront endpoint (`*.cloudfront.net`) rather than the API Gateway endpoint (`*.execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com`).

The CloudFront endpoint can be found by going to API Gateway -> Custom Domain Names. A CloudFront domain should be listed under "Target Domain Name".

Comment: That is the case for _Edge Optimized_ endpoints. I'm wondering if there is a way to set up this with _Regional_ ones (*.execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com).

Comment: I'm also facing same issue but i don't see any Target domain name. I'm having regional endpoint.